# T test failed in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

Iam using R to run a large number using input from a delimited table which is compost of   40000  row and 4 col. iam trying to implement the t test ,p value , but i have  error which is (the data are essentially constant) , i used the for loop and apply for both case i had same issue  the code is:

```
NormData3= NormData1[1:40000,1:5]
for(i in 1:nrow(NormData3)) {
g1=NormData3[i,2:3] 
g2=NormData3[i,4:5] 
p[i]=t.test(g1,g2,var.equal=TRUE)$p.value
 }
```

I don't know what is the problem ??

Comment: What error? Give us some sample of data.

Answer (score 3):

It's nice that the software recognizes situations in which a sensible 
answer can't be computed.  At that point, there are two possible actions: 
(1) stop with an informative error, and (2) silently return NA.

If you are running this in a iterative loop, you want the second output. Here is the small function for that :

```
     my.t.test.p.value <- function(...) {
    obj<-try(t.test(...), silent=TRUE)
    if (is(obj, "try-error")) return(NA) else return(obj$p.value)
}
```

Use this function instead of t.test in your code. This will not disturb your loop and allows  it to continue.